# Implementing generic map [from HW]

Tags: c++

As part of my C++ HW I have to implement a generic Map container.

The map I should implement should have an iterator and a constant_iterator.
I have decided to store data in the map within a node [like in a linked list].

I was provided with map_example.cpp, and my task is to write map.h so that map_example would compile.

My question is about the following lines of code within map_example.cpp

```
Map<std::string,int> msi;
msi.insert("Alice",5);
msi.insert("Bob",8);
msi.insert("Charlie",0);

// print map
for(Map<std::string,int>::const_iterator it = msi.begin(); it != msi.end(); ++it) 
{
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    /*
    * prints:
    * Alice:5
    * Bob:11
    * Charlie:0
    */
}
```

From this code, I understand that I have to overload the "*" operator, but I'm not sure what to return in order to enable this loop to print map content.

One of my ideas is to implement something like:
1. iterator::getKey()
2. iterator::getData()
3. operator "*" will return a string, howerve I'm not sure how to create a string from generic data.

What is the best way to implement the map tu support such functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do something similar to what `std::map<K, V>` does which returns `std::pair<K const, V>&` or `std::pair<K const, V> const&` depending on whether `iterator` or `const_iterator` is used. However, `std::pair<T0, T1>` doesn't have an output operator while the type you need to return should have an output iterator defined.

Answer (score 0):

The specific question seems to be how you can go about generating a string from a variable with generic type. This is one possible answer; there are many more.

You've worked with streams before (cin and cout, for example, are streams). You may have noticed that you can put a variety of types into them using operator << (ints, strings, what have you). It's also very easy to provide custom printers for such streams for your own types by providing an overload for operator << for your specific type.

You could require that the generic types for your map must support stream insertion via operator <<. With that, you can use the right kind of stream to build a string (hint: there is such a stream in the standard library).